# Returning ACF custom field from publish_post

Tags: hooks, advanced-custom-fields, save-post, publish

I'm trying to return a custom field as soon as a post gets published. I'm using the `publish_post` (or `{status}_{post_type}`) action, but it looks like the custom fields are created after the hook.

My code in `functions.php`:

```
function create_recurring_posts( $ID, $post ) {
    logMe(print_r(get_post_custom($ID), true));
}
add_action( 'publish_profile', 'create_recurring_posts', 10, 2 );
```

The `logMe()` function just logs the output to a file for testing purposes. My problem is, when I create the profile post, the only custom fields that get returned are `_edit_last` and `_edit_lock`. But when I view the page afterwards, where I have the same `get_post_custom()` function being ran, I see the other custom field I need.

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields for the field creation. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your action is triggered in `wp_transition_post_status()` which gets called by `wp_insert_post()` *before* the action `save_post` is triggered. `save_post` is the typical action to handle custom fields. ACF also works on this.

Basically you have to wait until ACF is done with its stuff, means you'll have to hook to `save_post` with a priority > 10 or better use `wp_insert_post` which runs right after `save_post`.

To track the post status transition, you can use a simple »log« like this:

```
<?php

namespace WPSE199070;

class PublishedTransitionLog {

    /**
     * @type array
     */
    private $status_log = [];

    /**
     * logs a published post id 
     * 
     * @wp-hook publish_profile
     *
     * @param int $post_id
     */
    public function published_post( $post_id ) {

        $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
        if ( ! isset( $this->status_log[ $blog_id ] ) )
            $this->status_log[ $blog_id ] = [];

        if ( in_array( $post_id, $this->status_log[ $blog_id ] ) )
            return;

        $this->status_log[ $blog_id ][] = $post_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $post_id
     * @return bool
     */
    public function post_published( $post_id ) {

        $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
        if ( ! isset( $this->status_log[ $blog_id ] ) )
            return FALSE;

        return in_array( $post_id, $this->status_log[ $blog_id ] );
    }
}

class PublishPostHandler {

    /**
     * @type PublishedTransitionLog
     */
    private $log;

    public function __construct( PublishedTransitionLog $log ) {

        $this->log = $log;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $post_id
     * @param \WP_Post $post 
     * @param bool $updated
     */
    public function update( $post_id, \WP_Post $post, $updated ) {

        if ( ! $this->log->post_published( $post_id ) )
            return;

        // do your stuff here
    }
}

$transition_log = new PublishedTransitionLog;
$handler        = new PublisPostHandler( $transition_log );

add_action( 'publish_profile', array( $transition_log, 'published_post' ) );
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', array( $handler, 'update', 10, 3 ) );
```

Let me explain this. The first class, `PublishedTransitionLog` listens to the action `publish_profile` and stores each published post for each blog internally. It also provides a method to check if a post was published before.

The second class should provide your logic and depends on the first class. If the post was not published it does just nothing.

This way you can listen independently to tow different hooks.

Answer (score 2):

@David explained why your code doesn't work and sketched out a solution (use `save_post` instead). However, you can "chain" hooks together so that you should still be able to use the transition filters to control execution:

```
function create_recurring_posts( $ID, $post ) {
  add_action(
    'save_post',
    function() {
      // debug, since I don't have a `logMe()` function :)
      var_dump(print_r(get_post_custom($ID), true));
      die;
    },
    PHP_INT_MAX,
    1
  );   
}
add_action( 'publish_profile', 'create_recurring_posts', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That's a notable architectural improvement, but you would still have to check the blog context in your `save_post` handler as well as compare the post IDs as you can not rely that other plugins update posts or switching the blog context on this hook. That's why I suggested to use `wp_insert_post` instead.